# why doesn't jquery insert created span into two divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following html:

```
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
```

When I run the following code in jquery:

```
$(function () {
    var span  = $("<span>name</span>");
    $("#one").append(span);
    $("#two").append(span);
});
```

The span is added only to the last div:

```
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"><span>name</span></div>
```

I'd expect it to be added to the both divs, why it's not?

Comment: Why is an object being created at first place? typeOf span === object. Rather by just adding a string could have solved the issue. :-)
var span = "<span>name</span>";

http://jsfiddle.net/to923zjc/

Comment: the question is not about how to insert the span into two divs, the question is _why_ it isn't inserted :)

Comment: A object is automatically passed by reference, without the need to specifically state it.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605640/javascript-by-reference-vs-by-value

Comment: you're missing the point of the question, sorry... and again, in JS it's always pass by value, although the value can be either a primitive or a reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each `DOM` element can be connected to one specific parent. You can't append same `DOM` element to two DOM parents. **[Refer SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11673609/use-javascript-to-draw-a-single-dom-element-in-two-places/11673746#11673746)**

In that case, you must `clone` the node.

```js
   $(function () {
    var span  = $("<span>name</span>");
    $("#one").append(span);
    $("#two").append(span.clone());
});
```

```html
  
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, "it's pass by reference" doesn't make much sense to me without specifying that each DOM node can have only one parent, like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11673746/2545680) does. Please, expand you answer with this bit of information from the linked answer and I'll accept your answer.

Comment: And it's pass by value still, although the value being a reference :)

Comment: Updated it and added a link to that SO question as well.

Answer (score 2):

update your script

```
$(function () {
    var span  = $("<span>name</span>");
    $("#one, #two").append(span);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

use below code it will work  . [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nishit_maheta/58o3kssh/)

a `DOM` element can't append twice.

```
$("<span>name</span>").appendTo("#one,#two");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `clone()`

```
var span  = $("<span>name</span>");
    $("#one").append(span);
    $("#two").append(span.clone());
```

Answer (score 1):

What happens is, your element **does get appended** to `#one`, but immediately it is again appended to `#two`

```
$(function () {
    var span  = $("<span>name</span>");
    $("#one").append(span);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#two").append(span);
    },2000)
});
```

Check this **[Fiddle with timeout](http://jsfiddle.net/shaun1ak/bzoppxsk/)**

Use combined selector : `appendTo('#one,#two')`

---

**Answer**

```
$(function () {
    var span  = $("<span>name</span>");
    $(span).appendTo("#one,#two");
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/shaun1ak/bzoppxsk/1/)**

Comment: yeah ,thanks, I've already found an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11673746/2545680)

Answer (score 0):

Hi you could try this also

```
$(function () {
    var span  = $("<span>name</span>");
   $("#one").append(span);
    $("#two").append(span.html());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/72ky7o28/